# Define in C++ new environment variable and use it in bat file

Tags: c++

It is very simple, I want to define a new environment variable in C++ using SetEnvironmentVariable, and then call a bat file that use it. This is my c++ code;

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = { 0 };
STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };

SetEnvironmentVariable("GSDebbugingDir", "Hello");

BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL,
                                    "dummy.bat"),
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    FALSE,
                                    CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    &startupInfo,
                                    &processInformation);
```

And my dummy.bat file is :

```
@echo off    
echo GSDebbugingDir = %GSDebbugingDir%    
if defined GSDebbugingDir mkdir c:\temp\dummy    
pause
```

But this didn't out the value of GSDebbugingDir variable. What is the problem?

Comment: `CreateProcess` documentation says you need to provide environment in 7th parameter. In you code it is `NULL`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa. `SetEnvironmentVariable` modifies only environment of calling process. Also see example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/changing-environment-variables

Comment: @mvidelgauz the documentation says about CreateProcess 7th parameter:  "If this parameter is NULL, the new process uses the environment of the calling process.". And this is thesituation I want to do it becasue I am modyfing the caller environment.

Comment: You are not checking the return value from `SetEnvironmentVariable()`.

Comment: Is UNICODE defined in your build environment?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your script is actually running?  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60100978/edit) your post with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateProcess` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) says:

> To run a batch file, **you must start the command interpreter**; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

Which makes sense because a .bat file by itself is not an executable module by itself.
But, contrary to what the doc says the following code worked for me with `UseApplicationName` NOT #defined, i.e. with "cmd.exe" placed into `commandLine`

Also, to see the output of the bat file you probably want to remove that `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag

```
//#define UseApplicationName
#ifdef UseApplicationName
TCHAR  commandLine[] = _T(" /c dummy.bat");
#else
TCHAR  commandLine[] = _T("cmd.exe /c dummy.bat");
#endif

BOOL result = CreateProcess(
#ifdef UseApplicationName
    _T("cmd.exe"),
#else
    NULL,
#endif
    commandLine,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0, //CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &startupInfo,
    &processInformation);
```

BTW pay attention that

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string).